# Ongoing Automatic Investment Fee

Tags: united-states, investing, financial-literacy, fees

When a DRIP plan says "Ongoing Automatic Investment Fee", is that the amount of money they take every month?

In the case of [Hershey's DRIP](https://www-us.computershare.com/investor/3x/plans/planslist.asp?planid=1013&state=eStateDisplayPlanSummary), it says it's $2. Does that mean if someone invests $50 a month, only $48 actually goes towards buying the stock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the [plan documentation](https://www-us.computershare.com/Content/Download.asp?docId=%7B5ECA3F68-1219-46CF-8A84-256E0514F91D%7D&cc=US&lang=en&bhjs=1&fla=1&theme=cpu), yes, that is what it means.  Each purchase by bank debit, whether one-time or automatic, costs $2 plus $0.06 per share; so if you invested $50, you would get slightly less than $48 in stock as a result (depending on the per-share price).

> Schedule of Fees
>
> Purchases
>
> > – A one-time $15.00 enrollment fee to establish a new
> >     account for a non-shareholder will be deducted from the
> >     purchase amount.
> >
> > – Dividend reinvestment: The Hershey Company pays the
> >     transaction fee and per share* fee on your behalf.
> >
> > – Each optional cash purchase by one-time online bank
> >     debit will entail a transaction fee of $2.00 plus $0.06 per
> >     share* purchased.
> >
> > – Each optional cash purchase by check will entail a
> >     transaction fee of $5.00 plus $0.06 per share* purchased.
> >
> > – If funds are automatically deducted from your checking or
> >     savings account, the transaction fee is $2.00 plus $0.06
> >     per share* purchased. Funds will be withdrawn on the
> >     10th of each month, or the preceding business day if the
> >     10th is not a business day.
> >
> > – Fees will be deducted from the purchase amount.
> >
> > – Returned check and rejected ACH debit fee is $35.00.